# docker network not connecting my services together

Tags: python, django, postgresql, docker-compose, dockerfile

I am having an issue with docker network not connecting my services together, I have a postgres image and a python image that need them to connect but at the moment when I call to connect to postgres service from python service my connection is denied. I have tried to open port 5432 and all host to see if I could get any connection but the same error would occur, tried using the service name to connect to it and the same issue continues to happen. anyone have any ideas why ?

```
=========================================Django settings.py==============================================
DATABASES = {
            'default': {
                'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.postgresql_psycopg2',
                'NAME': 'postgres',
                'USER': 'postgres',
                'PASSWORD': 'postgres',
                'HOST': 'db',
                'PORT': '5432',
        }
    }
......
ALLOWED_HOSTS = ['*']

========================================Error==========================================================


ERROR: Service 'web' failed to build: The command '/bin/sh
-c python manage.py makemigrations' returned a non-zero code: 1
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/db/backends/base/base.py", line 217, in ensure_connection
    self.connect()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/db/backends/base/base.py", line 195, in connect
    self.connection = self.get_new_connection(conn_params)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/db/backends/postgresql/base.py", line 178, in get_new_connection
    connection = Database.connect(**conn_params)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/psycopg2/__init__.py", line 126, in connect
    conn = _connect(dsn, connection_factory=connection_factory, **kwasync)
psycopg2.OperationalError: could not translate host name "db" to address: No address associated with hostname
The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "manage.py", line 21, in <module>
    main()
  File "manage.py", line 17, in main
    execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 381, in execute_from_command_line
    utility.execute()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 375, in execute
    self.fetch_command(subcommand).run_from_argv(self.argv)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 323, in run_from_argv
    self.execute(*args, **cmd_options)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 364, in execute
    output = self.handle(*args, **options)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 83, in wrapped
    res = handle_func(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/core/management/commands/makemigrations.py", line 101, in handle
    loader.check_consistent_history(connection)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/db/migrations/loader.py", line 283, in check_consistent_history
    applied = recorder.applied_migrations()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/db/migrations/recorder.py", line 73, in applied_migrations
    if self.has_table():
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/db/migrations/recorder.py", line 56, in has_table
    return self.Migration._meta.db_table in self.connection.introspection.table_names(self.connection.cursor())
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/db/backends/base/base.py", line 256, in cursor
    return self._cursor()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/db/backends/base/base.py", line 233, in _cursor
    self.ensure_connection()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/db/backends/base/base.py", line 217, in ensure_connection
    self.connect()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/db/utils.py", line 89, in __exit__
    raise dj_exc_value.with_traceback(traceback) from exc_value
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/db/backends/base/base.py", line 217, in ensure_connection
    self.connect()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/db/backends/base/base.py", line 195, in connect
    self.connection = self.get_new_connection(conn_params)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/db/backends/postgresql/base.py", line 178, in get_new_connection
    connection = Database.connect(**conn_params)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/psycopg2/__init__.py", line 126, in connect
    conn = _connect(dsn, connection_factory=connection_factory, **kwasync)
django.db.utils.OperationalError: could not translate host
name "db" to address: No address associated with hostname

=============================Docker Compose File=================================

version: "3"

services:
  db:
    image: postgres:12
    volumes:
      - /home/--path-to-folder/data/postgres:/var/lib/postgresql/data
    restart: always
    environment:
      POSTGRES_PASSWORD: postgres
    ports:
      - "5432:5432"

  web:
    build: ./backend
    command: sh -c "python backend/manage.py makemigrations && python backend/manage.py migrate && python backend/manage.py runserver 0.0.0.0:8000"
    # command: python3 app/backend/manage.py runserver 0.0.0.0:8000
    volumes:
      - .:/backend
    links:
      - db
    ports:
      - "8000:8000"
    depends_on:
      - db

  # frontend:
  #   build: ./frontend
  #   command: serve -s build -l 3000
  #   volumes:
  #     - ./frontend:/app/frontend
  #   ports:
  #     - "3000:3000"
  #   depends_on:
  #     - db

volumes:
  postgres_data:
```

Comment: In docker-compose the hostname usually starts with the folder name and an underscore, then comes the service name and a number. Or you can set one explicitly in the configuration.

Comment: @KlausD I just tried with what you recommended and it is still the same issue `docker-compose run web
Starting cyber-dive-app_db_1 ... done
Building web....
django.db.utils.OperationalError: could not translate host
name "cyber-dive-app_db_1" to address: No address associated with hostname

ERROR: Service 'web' failed to build: The command '/bin/sh
-c python manage.py makemigrations' returned a non-zero code: 1`

Answer (score 0):

Maybe your "db" is not initialised before "web" did you added `depends_on`, it will make sure all dependencies are loaded before loading web.

In your "web" service add,

```
depends_on:
  - db
```

Comment: db is running at all times, and created before web is ran

Comment: can you post your docker-compose file?

Comment: i added the compose file at the end of the error, thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0):

Remove the `links: db` it's not needed and possible affects, since docker-compose services connects to each other by their names by default. Also in my case I've used `networks:default:external` and `networks:default:aliases` for some services but it's not your case this time.

Comment: so I just tried removing it and I still face the same issue and I even made my allowed host to allow all and same with the database connections

Comment: Did you check that db is working? I just test db config from your file and it's works, I've done to connect to it from my django-app. Try to remove `restart: always` and check that it's run successfully.

Answer (score 0):

Could you try to just remove the `ports` section for `db` service?

Indeed, you don't need to publish ports to the host since this is `web` service which will connect to the `db` service, nobody else.